Please assist me with obtaining output from RVC
PLeas Help.
When running the following source code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o5dZtcTu1rEGe3NPOcto4wr5UUn5cQlT?usp=drive_link
I receive a zip file containing two formats: pth and index. Now, what should I do to convert this file to an mp3 format? This is RVC code, and I'm unable to get a proper output from it.
pleas Help .
In the first step, I installed and connected to the driver.
In the second step, I only wrote the model name with letters and then entered the path of the folder containing the sound files.
In the third step, I entered the name again and configured the settings. I also set the batch_size to 2, matching the number of files in the folder.
Then, in the fourth step, I saved the necessary folders on the main driver page, and finally, in the last step, I separated the two necessary model files from the folders and saved them in a zip file.
I followed the mentioned steps, and in addition, I obtained several types of output files: Harvest, pm, rmvpe, gpu. I expected the output file to be an audio file, but it was a file with the extension pth and index that I couldn't use. What should I do?
pleas help.
